# connect four draw condition java

Tags: java

This code works properly for connect four game except draw condition. I think for draw condition i have to go over all the cell and check whether  they are full or not.I don't know how to loop over all cells and check them if they are empty or not and if they are full return " draw". what i wrote  here just check the first raw of board. it sound very easy but i don't know how to do it. any comment appreciate.

```
 import  java.util.Scanner;

 public class conncetFour {
 public static String[][] createpattern(){
     String [][] f = new String[7][15];
    for (int i=0;i<f.length ; i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<f[i].length ; j++){
            if (j%2 == 0) f[i][j] = "|";
            else f[i][j] = " " ;
            if (i == 6 ) f[i][j] = "-";
        }
    }
    return f;
}

public static void printpattern(String[][] f) {
    for(int i=0;i<f.length;i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<f[i].length;j++){
            System.out.print(f[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
public static void dropRedpattern(String [][] f){
    System.out.println("Drop a red disk at column (0-6): ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = 2*input.nextInt()+1;
    for (int i=5;i>= 0;i--){
        if (f[i][c] == " "){
            f[i][c] = "R";
            break;
        }
    }
}
public static void dropyellowpattern(String[][] f){
    System.out.println("Drop a yellow disk at column (0-6): ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = 2*input.nextInt()+1;
    for(int i =5;i>= 0 ; i--){
        if (f[i][c] == " "){
            f[i][c] = "Y";
            break;
        }
    }
}
public static String checkwinner(String[][] f){
    for(int i =0;i<6;i++){
        for (int j= 0; j<7;j+=2){
            if((f[i][j+1] != " ")
                    && (f[i][j+3] != " ")
                    && (f[i][j+5] != " ")
                    && (f[i][j+7] != " ")
                    &&((f[i][j+1] == f[i][j+3])
                            &&(f[i][j+3] == f[i][j+5])
                            && (f[i][j+5] == f[i][j+7])))
                return f[j][j+1];
        }
    }
    for (int i=1;i<15;i+=2){
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if((f[j][i] != " ")
                    && (f[j+1][i] != " ")
                    && (f[j+2][i] != " ")
                    && (f[j+3][i] != " ")
                    && ((f[j][i] == f[j+1][i])
                    && (f[j+1][i] == f[j+2][i])
                    && (f[j+2][i] == f[j+3][i])))
                      return f[j][i];  
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<9;j+=2){
            if((f[i][j] != " ")
                    && (f[i+1][j+2] != " ")
                    && (f[i+2][j+4] != " ")
                    && (f[i+3][j+6] != " ")
                    && ((f[i][j] == f[i+1][j+2])
                    && (f[i+1][j+2] == f[i+2][j+4])
                    && (f[i+2][j+4] == f[i+3][j+6])))
                      return f[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for (int j=7;j<15;j+=2){
            if((f[i][j] != " ")
                    && (f[i+1][j-2] != " ")
                    && (f[i+2][j-4] != " ")
                    && (f[i+3][j-6] != " ")
                    && ((f[i][j] == f[i+1][j-2])
                    && (f[i+1][j-2] == f[i+2][j-4])
                    && (f[i+2][j-4] == f[i+3][j-6])))
                      return f[i][j];
        }
    }
 //checking for draw condition 

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<7;j+=2){
            if((f[i][j+1] != " ") 
                    && (f[i][j+3] != " ")
                    &&(f[i][j+5] != " ")
                    &&(f[i][j+7] != " "))
                return "draw";
        }
    }

    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[][] f = createpattern();
    boolean repeat = true;
    int count = 0;
    printpattern(f);
    while(repeat){
        if (count % 2 == 0) dropRedpattern(f);
        else dropyellowpattern(f);
        count++;
        printpattern(f);
        if(checkwinner(f) != null ){
            if (checkwinner(f) == "R")
                System.out.println("red palyer won!");
            else if (checkwinner(f)== "Y")
                System.out.println("yellow player won!");
            else if (checkwinner(f) == "draw")
                System.out.println("Tha game draw!");
            repeat = false;
          }

      }
  }

 }
```

Comment: what shoud i do instead?

Comment: ok thank you, how can i check that if all the cells are empty or not? how loop for all cell?